# How to setup sonar in Azure?

Tags: azure, sonarqube

I am planning to setup sonar in VSTS for that I tried searching blogs and stack overflow.I got few links to setup sonar but all I need is to have Microsoft SQL windows server 2012 R2 as a IAAS. I need dedicated VM as IAAS(Infrastructure as a service) to configure sonar in Azure after creating Microsoft SQL server VM I can give that endpoint in VSTS and can run sonar.But in my company we are having all VM's as a PAAS(Platform as a service).My organization is not ready to have VM as IAAS.So kindly provide the solution how can I configure sonar in VSTS.

The below link received from stackOverflow.

http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-setup-a-sonarqube-server-in-azure

Comment: Have you considered using SonarCloud? => https://sonarcloud.io

Comment: @ Fabrice - SonarSource Team,Since I am a very new to sonar and Azure.Could you please detail the steps.So that I will follow the same to setup for my projects.Please help me with the steps how to start setting up sonar in VSTS to azure.

Comment: Please read https://about.sonarcloud.io/get-started/

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube is designed to use a dedicated server and needs access to a database. Take a look at the [system requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) for details. There is no way to host it inside of VSTS.

If your organization isn't ready to do IaaS with Azure, then you have two options. The first option is to setup a SonarQube server in your office or data center and make it publicly accessible.

If that isn't an option, then your only other option is to make use of SonarCloud as Fabrice mentioned in the comments. Take a look at this [blog post](https://elevate-org.com/2017/10/14/configure-sonarqube-with-vsts-for-continuous-code-quality/) for setting up VSTS and SonarCloud.

Comment: ,Thanks so much for your inputs.The blog looks like over complicated.So,my leads accepted to setup using Private agent.So could you please help me with the steps how to setup sonar with Private agent?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wish to hosted in SonarQube in Azure then you are in luck. You can make a VSTS/Azure DevOps Project where you add this Github: [ARM Template for VM, network and DB setup for SonarQube](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sonarqube-azuresql) to your a GIT repo.

This will give you the possiblity to have you secrets safe in VSTS/Azure Dev but automatically support the SonarQube setup from Azure DevOps with Cloud Infrastructure.